# Prettier single quote for JavaScript and JSON, double quote for HTML, Sass and CSS

Tags: prettier

In VSCode, whenever I save a file, Prettier changes all single quotes to double quotes.
I want to keep this behaviour for SCSS and CSS files, **but want to change it for JavaScript and JSON files.**

I am aware of the setting **"prettier.singleQuote": true**, but this will change double quotes to single quotes in all file types.

**How can I activate single quote only for JavaScript and JSON files and keep double quote for SCSS and CSS files?**

Comment: Did the accepted answer work for you with JSON files? Single quotes [are invalid when surrounding property names or string values in JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and prettier seems to [appropriately] ignore `singleQuote: true` there for me.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use a Prettier configuration file in your project folder: `.prettierrc`

Inside your config file use Prettier overrides: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides

So in your case this example config should work (.prettierrc):

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["**/*.css", "**/*.scss", "**/*.html"],
            "options": {
                "singleQuote": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see here you are ignoring ALL html files, what about a situation where I want <script> tags within an HTML file to be formatted with single quotes, but I want the <style> tags within that same file to be formatted with doubles? Is there any way to configure it this way?

Comment: Thx! But why it's necessary to do this, when I already configured this in my vs code settings (which wasn't working so I ended up googling it)..